# How to click an AngularJS button on a website

Tags: .net, angularjs, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I fill in a website to login and put in a number.  Thats seems to work but I can't do the event button somehow.  Maybe it is simple but I can't clicked it from code in .NET.

in .NET

```
Web.Document.GetElementById("hwbOrPiece").InnerText = txtCID.Text
Web.Document.InvokeScript("query()")
```

Website

```
<button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button"
        ng-transclude="" aria-label="Search" ng-click="query()">

    <i class="material-icons md-24 ng-scope">search</i>
</button>

<button class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button"
        ng-transclude="" aria-label="Search" ng-click="query()">

    <i class="material-icons md-24 ng-scope">search</i>
</button>
```

The input field " hwbOrPiece " works, I see the value.  Manually, I press on the search button, I get my result.  But of course, I want to automate it.  So I want the event 'query()' to execute in my code.

Some help would be great!

Kind regards,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

After trying (of course) and looking a lot of information, I can trigger the button:

```
    Dim HtmlElementcol As HtmlElementCollection = Web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each ele As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcol
        'Check the attributtes you want
        If ele.InnerText = "search " Then 'The space must be there
            ele.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

But my next problem is that the value can not found after clicking the button.
I think I have to update the angular value to?

The HTML code:

```
                <input type="text" ng-model="hwbOrPiece" ng-trim="true" awb-or-piece="" md-no-asterisk="" name="hwbOrPiece" id="hwbOrPiece" maxlength="35" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; query()" class="ng-valid md-input ng-valid-response-validator ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-awb-validator ng-valid-srk-validator ng-valid-piece-validator ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" style=""><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
```